# Filter a neo4j map projection

Tags: database, neo4j, cypher

I'm attempting to build up a map projection that has a dynamic flag in it, so I initially set the flag to false for all nodes, then union the results with specific users and set their flag to true as below

```
MATCH (u:User)
WITH u, false as has_policyflag
RETURN u{.UPN, has_policyflag:has_policyflag}
UNION
MATCH (u:User)-[*1..2]-(:Policy{id:"4d3e7650-1ee0-4254-9ec1-30f2a271a7a5"})
WITH u, true AS has_policyflag
RETURN u{.UPN, has_policyflag:has_policyflag}
UNION
MATCH (u:User)-[*1..2]-(:Policy{id: "806134f2-7738-4da2-a725-3837f8c5d769"})
WITH u, true AS has_policyflag
RETURN u{.UPN, has_policyflag:has_policyflag}
```

What this gets me is a map projection of ALL the user UPNs and their policy flag, but what I'd really like to be able to do is filter this down so I only return the ones which are true. Is this possible or am I taking the wrong approach?

Answer (score 0):

You can use  a single `MATCH` clause and `OPTIONAL MATCH` for each policy. Then you can set the `has_policyflag` to `true` if either of the `OPTIONAL MATCH` clauses match, and filter the results accordingly

```
MATCH (u:User)
OPTIONAL MATCH (u)-[*1..2]-(p1:Policy {id: "4d3e7650-1ee0-4254-9ec1-30f2a271a7a5"})
OPTIONAL MATCH (u)-[*1..2]-(p2:Policy {id: "806134f2-7738-4da2-a725-3837f8c5d769"})
WITH u, p1, p2
WHERE p1 IS NOT NULL OR p2 IS NOT NULL
RETURN u{.UPN, has_policyflag: (p1 IS NOT NULL OR p2 IS NOT NULL)}
```

First match all `User` nodes and then uses two `OPTIONAL MATCH` clauses to find if the user is connected to either of the two `Policy` nodes. The `WHERE` clause is used to filter the users that are connected to at least one of the policies, and the `RETURN` clause sets the `has_policyflag` property to `true` for the users that match the conditions.